# How can I calculate changes in variance as sample size expands using R?

Tags: r

I would like to calculate a new variance each time my sample size grows. Say I have some data like so

```
data <- data.frame(run = c(1:10), variable = c(runif(10)))

#looks like
   run  variable
1    1 0.3952740
2    2 0.9851133
3    3 0.3168918
4    4 0.5502555
5    5 0.2313667
6    6 0.3825951
7    7 0.6286789
8    8 0.4171103
9    9 0.8215275
10  10 0.3755391
```

I would like to add a new column that has the variance of the variable for that run and all previous runs. So, skipping the first row, the second row of the column variance would have the variance of run 1 and 2, the third column would have variance of row 1, 2,and 3. etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ["online" algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm). Example implementation:

```
x <- runif(10)
s <- cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)
s <- cumsum((x - c(0, s[-length(s)]))*(x - s))/(0:(length(x) - 1))
```

Compare to a naive approach that calls `var` multiple times:

```
all.equal(s, sapply(seq_along(x), \(i) var(x[1:i])))
#> [1] TRUE
```